# PHP can't write files in IIS using Edge and Windows Authentication

Tags: php, iis, microsoft-edge, windows-authentication

I am running PHP through IIS on windows, and using the Integrated Authentication for using domain users.

The following code works when accessing a page in IE 11, Chrome and Firefox.

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$dir = realpath($dir.'/../storage/logs');

$filename = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'my-log.log';
file_put_contents($filename, 'hello world');
```

When accessed in MS Edge

```
PHP Warning: file_put_contents(C:\websites\my-site\api\storage\logs\my-log.log): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
C:\websites\my-site\api\public\permissions.php on line 11
```

(It works in the Edge-Dev that is based on Chromium, it is only a problem in the traditional / EdgeHTML version that has the problem.)

The code works in Edge too if I turn off the windows authentication. I know that I am typing my password correctly because if I don't I get a 401 unauthorised message from IIS.

This issue is not just my computer; it has failed on all 4 laptops we've tried it on. But does not seem to affect servers, only desktop Windows.

**Update**

As per Deepak-MSFT's suggestion I added my computer's name to the intranet, but it didn't change anything. The name is like `laptop-4.example.com` I added it both with and without http and `*.example.com` was already in trusted sites, leaving it in or removing it does not seem to change anything.

Comment: For testing purpose, can you please try to add that specific site in the intranet site zone list from internet options and again try to have the same test? Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT - I tried that and updated question. Didn't seem to help :(

Comment: Please try to keep the site in intranet site zone list and remove it from trusted site list and make the test.

Comment: I have removed the wildcard from trusted sites, and don't have the site in there. Same problem

Comment: I want to confirm with you that is your intranet settings is at medium-low level? If not try to set it on medium low level. Also if possible for you than try to post a snapshot of the setting may give us the better idea.

Comment: Setting to medium-low, or low and restarting Edge does not help :(

Comment: This much setting will generally help to make IWA work. not sure if issue caused by any other IIS or PHP related settings. You can also try to review it may give some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for some reason Edge seems to prefer having **NTLM before Negotiate** in the list. Don't know why, but it has solved the problem. I can reliably revert back to Negotiate to cause the issues again, so its pretty likely to be the cause.

[image: Auth setting location]